# Pytorch resize specific dimension while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, transformation, torchvision

I have images, where for some height>=width, while for others height<width.
I want to resize the images to a fixed height, while maintaining aspect ratio.
I have tried using torchvision.transforms.Resize([Documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Resize.html)), however, there is an issue i encountered which i don't know how to solve using library functions.

I have two possibilities, i can either provide two ints, indicating the size of the output, or a single int, indicating the size of the SMALLEST side of my output image after resizing.

For example: image1 is 64x200 (HxW), while image2 is 200x64. Resizing with resize(32, ..)(image) will yield out_image1 of size 32x100, and out_image2 of size 100x32. However, i want the second image to be 32x10.

So how do i specify a particular dimension, which is to be scaled to my specified size, while the other one is always implicitly rescaled while keeping aspect ratio?

Edit: So i basically solved it, it requires me to make a new instance of Resize, giving it two ints and requiring me to calculate the new width manually. If there is a more elegant solution already implemented, i'ld still like to know. Having to instantiate Resize repeatedly prohibits me from handing my Dataset class the transformation as a composition. Instead i have to implement the resize transformation in the Dataset *getitem* function directly, which makes it less flexible, by just handing my dataset the composed transformation directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a custom transform that resizes the images based on their aspect ratio. This transform takes a fixed height value and resizes the input image. this is a roughly schema of how you should proceed.

```
import math
from torchvision.transforms import functional as F

class FixedHeightResize:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        
    def __call__(self, img):
        w, h = img.size
        aspect_ratio = float(h) / float(w)
        new_w = math.ceil(self.size / aspect_ratio)
        return F.resize(img, (self.size, new_w))
```

Next, you can use it to resize the input image to have a fixed height of 32 while maintaining aspect ratio.

```
img = Image.open("image.jpg")

transform = transforms.Compose([
    FixedHeightResize(32)
])

out_img = transform(img)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, that seems like the most obvious solution i somehow didn't think about :)